# The question is about array in C++ for more understanding in programming subject

Tags: c++, arrays

Any **expression** that evaluates to an integral value may be used as an **index** true or false?

Comment: What do you think? If you explain how you see things you'll get better answers. Any misunderstandings you have will be corrected. But true I would say, I can't think of any exceptions.

Comment: If you don't want to think it through, pick an answer - you only have a 50% chance of being wrong.     Thinking the question through needs no more than a minute or two though, even for a beginner.

Comment: An index to what? Please be more specific in your question. Perhaps include a short code sample to illustrate what you are asking about.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I find the answer. Integral value can be used as an index or subscript. Example of the we can set **int a,b,c; ** 'a' 'b' 'c' is a index